# Excel macro parameter is passed with either a reference or a constant

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

In Excel, I have written a vba function `Separate` like this:

```
Function Separate(sp As String, ParamArray ArgList() As Variant)
    Dim paramLoop As Long
    Dim curRng As Range
    Separate = ArgList(0).Cells(1, 1).Value
    Dim flag As Boolean
    flag = False
    For paramLoop = 0 To UBound(ArgList)
        For Each curRng In ArgList(paramLoop)
            If flag Then
                Separate = Separate & sp & curRng.Value
            End If
            flag = True
        Next curRng
    Next paramLoop
End Function
```

This function is intended to join an arbitrary number of contents separated by a string given as the first argument.

For example, `=Separate(", ",A1:B2,A2)` returns `Alan, Bill, Carl, Dale, Bill` successfully. (Suppose these names have been stored in the cells `A1`, `A2`, `B1` and `B2`.)

It becomes a problem if a constant rather than a reference is passed to the second (and third and so on) argument, such as `=Separate(", ","Alan",A2:B2)`. This is because my code presupposes that the `ArgList() As Variant` are `Range` object.

How can vba determine whether each argument is passed with a reference or a constant? Or how to modify the code so that it does the same things regardless of whether an argument is passed with a reference or a constant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a VBA function which will determine the type of variable being dealt with: `VarType()`.

The `VarType` of a string is `vbString` (8); the `VarType` of a range is `vbArray+vbVariant` (8204). You need to test each element of your passed array and deal with it accordingly. One way to do this which is easy to follow is with `Select Case`:

```
Function Separate(sp As String, ParamArray ArgList() As Variant)
    Dim paramLoop As Long
    Dim curRng As Range
    Select Case VarType(ArgList(0))
        Case vbArray + vbVariant
            Separate = ArgList(0).Cells(1, 1).Value
        Case vbString
            Separate = ArgList(0)
    End Select
    Dim flag As Boolean
    flag = True
    For paramLoop = 1 To UBound(ArgList)
        Select Case VarType(ArgList(paramLoop))
            Case vbArray + vbVariant
                For Each curRng In ArgList(paramLoop)
                    If flag Then
                        Separate = Separate & sp & curRng.Value
                   End If
                    flag = True
                Next curRng
            Case vbString
                Separate = Separate & sp & ArgList(paramLoop)
        End Select
    Next paramLoop
End Function
```

And of course, the `Select` can be expanded for each of `vbInteger, vbLong, vbSingle, vbDouble, vbCurrency, vbDate, vbBoolean, vbVariant, vbDecimal, vbByte` and even `vbError` if you have an empty parameter.

Comment: Thank you. I wonder what 8204 is. Why a Range is 8204?

Comment: 8204 is an Array of Variants. (8192 is Array, and 12 is Variant).

Answer (score 2):

If you declare an argument as *Variant* in the function header, you can always determine what the caller **REALLY** passes you as follows:

```
Sub MAIN()
   x = WhatIsIt(Range("A1"))
   y = WhatIsIt("what ever")
End Sub

Public Function WhatIsIt(v As Variant) As String
   WhatIsIt = ""
   MsgBox TypeName(v)
End Function
```